# alternate to print STDERR

Tags: perl

I want to replace existing `print STDERR` statements in my codebase.

Apparently, I find them not very suitable to eyes, or is it just me. Should I be using `warn` knowing that It will be caught by `$SIG{_WARN_}` handler. Or is there any better option. And if yes, why use those options and not `print STDERR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of `print STDERR` is that you can see at once what will happen—you print something to STDERR. This may be a debug message, or something.

The `warn` function is slightly different:

1. It will trigger the warn handlers, and
2. it will append the line number, if you don't end with a newline.

You should probably use this for warnings, not for logging data

You might be also interested in the `Carp` family of functions. `carp` works like `warn`, but reports the line number/file from the point of call. `cluck` will `warn` with a stack trace.

But nothing prevents you from rolling your own. A functionally equivalent sub to `print STDERR` would be:

```
sub debug { print STDERR @_ }
```

You can now literally `s/print STDERR/debug/g` your source, except for that one occurence. Also, you will have to declare or import that `debug` function before you use it if you want to be able to leave out the parens around the arguments.

```
debug "this ", "is ", "DATA";
```

Point to consider: calling a sub is slooow, whereas `print` is a built-in opcode. You can trade beauty for performance, and vice versa.

Comment: No, I don't want to trade performance. Better should keep it with print, I guess.

Comment: Performance is a red herring. Sub call overhead is on the order of microseconds - unless you're writing thousands of messages _per second_, it won't be a noticeable performance impact. (If you _are_ writing that many messages per second, you're probably writing them to a file, in which case the relative performance matters even less because disk is many orders of magnitude slower than sub calls.) Optimize for readability. Don't micro-optimize for performance unless you have a problem - and even then, you'll get better results from optimizing algorithms, not statement choices.

Comment: @DaveSherohman I generally agree, except that I have witnessed some significant performance increase when refactoring elegant, OO Perl code to unmaintainable spaghetti mess ;-) However, I would only do so in performance-critical sections (Devel::NYTProf is our friend). One can have “the best of both worlds” with the `debug $message if CONSTANT` idiom. (PS: On my machine, a subroutine entry&exit takes 0.5–2.5 µs for an empty body. `print` takes 5× as long, even for `/dev/null`, so wrapping a sub around it is mostly, but not actually insignificant)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `debug` subroutine to wrap `print STDERR` would give you a lot of flexibility above and beyond what simple `print` or `warn` statements provide, such as the ability to turn debugging messages off or redirect them to different destinations.  For example, just off the top of my head:

```
sub debug {
  my ($msg, %param) = @_;

  $param{level} //= 1; # default if no level specified
  return if $param{level} < $config{log_level};

  given ($param{dest}) {
    when ('mail') { send_email_to_admin(subject => "Application Error!", body => $msg) }
    when ('log') { write_to_logfile($msg) }
    default { print STDERR $msg }
  }
}

debug('foo');   # goes to STDERR by default
$config{log_level} = 2;
debug('bar');  # message is ignored as unimportant at current logging level
debug('bar', level => 3, dest => mail); # still important; gets emailed to admin
```